# Python / psycopg2: cursor.fetchall() returns empty list on certain tables

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm getting empty results from certain tables, although the database is otherwise working fine (and the tables are definitely not empty).

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(###)
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = """SELECT 1"""
cursor.execute(query)
cursor.fetchall()
```

returns: `[(1,)]`

```
query = """SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE table_schema = 'public' """
cursor.execute(query)
cursor.fetchall()
```

returns: `[('table1',),('table2',)]`

```
query = """SELECT * FROM table1"""
cursor.execute(query)
cursor.fetchall()
```

returns: `[]`

The `cursor.rowcount` is also 0. Selecting from non-existant tables gives the correct error, so I know I have the table name correct. When my colleagues run identical code with identical connection strings, the function returns data. When I execute the same query in a client, the table has data. When I connect to the backup database instead, and re-run the above code, it returns data!

I'm really out of ideas for what might be causing this...

I'm on a fresh `miniconda` install with psycopg2 2.8.6 (py38hbcfaee0_1), on an M1 mac, Big Sur 11.2.3.

Comment: "identical code" means exactly the same file or just same-looking code? If only "same-looking", check if you don't accidentally do .fetchall() twice - it will exhaust the cursor first time so second will be empty. | How do you run the code? If from IDE like Pycharm, check if you're not in some debug mode

Comment: @h4z3 thanks a lot for your reply. "Identical" means, pulled from the same Git repo without any changes. I'm also calling .fetchall() exactly once each time. I run the code on a Mac, in JupyterLab, using miniconda. My coworkers also use JupyterLab, on Mac or Windows...

Comment: A `search_path` difference that is putting an empty table of the same name first? Try schema qualifying the table name.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianKlaver. I didn't have a chance to try that because the database stopped working entirely! We still have no idea what the problem is, all we can say is that it seems like something funny on AWS's side and try and solve the problem there...

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that there may be a transaction open that has not been committed or rolled back. This can cause the cursor to return empty results, even if there is data in the table. You can check if this is the case by running the following query before your SELECT statement:

`SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname = 'your_database_name';`

If you see a row with an open transaction (i.e., state is idle in transaction), you can either commit or roll back the transaction to close it. Another possibility is that there may be a permission issue with your user account. Make sure that your user has the appropriate permissions to read from the table. You can check this by running the following query:

```
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND table_name = 'your_table_name'
```

Make sure that is_updatable and is_insertable_into are both YES. If not, you may need to grant additional permissions to your user. Finally, it's possible that there may be a problem with the data itself. For example, if there are non-UTF-8 characters in the data, this can cause the cursor to return empty results. You can check if this is the case by running the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE your_column_name NOT LIKE '%UTF8%';
```

If you see any rows returned by this query, you may need to clean up the data before you can read it with the cursor.